# для чего используется кодировка Base64?

Tags: jwt

при использовании стандарта JWT заголовок и полезная нагрузка кодируются в Base64. Для чего это делается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположу, что это очень примитивная защита от непредвиденных ситуаций. При обработке заголовков могут сложиться, в том числе, такие ситуации:

- JWT содержит переводы строки, которые ошибочно будут приняты сервером за начало нового HTTP-заголовка (а если их два подряд, то это и вовсе окончит заголовочную часть запроса/ответа)
- Промежуточный сервер, передающий запрос на обработчик, не очень хорошо дружит с различными кодировками и понимает только ASCII, выбрасывая все остальное

Оба эти случая по-хорошему не должны случиться, но могут быть и могут потребовать значительное количество ресурсов на обратную раскрутку ситуации и выяснение причин появления. Base64 же гарантирует, что передаваться будут только слова в известном и всеми поддерживаемом шестидесятипятисимвольном алфавите, не содержащем управляющих символов (кроме, может быть, слэша, если JWT по каким-то причинам хочется использовать как часть пути в url, и знака "равно", если используется паддинг). Поэтому предположу, что такое преобразование делается для повышения совместимости и обхода возможных проблем еще до их появления.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Web Token (JWT) — содержит три блока, разделенных точками: заголовок, набор полей (claims) и подпись. Первые два блока представлены в JSON-формате и дополнительно закодированы в формат base64. Набор полей содержит произвольные пары имя/значения, притом стандарт JWT определяет несколько зарезервированных имен (iss, aud, exp и другие). Подпись может генерироваться при помощи и симметричных алгоритмов шифрования, и асимметричных. Кроме того, существует отдельный стандарт, отписывающий формат зашифрованного JWT-токена.
Пример подписанного JWT токена (после декодирования 1 и 2 блоков).
{ «alg»: «HS256», «typ»: «JWT» }.
{ «iss»: «auth.myservice.com», «aud»: «myservice.com», «exp»: «1435937883», «userName»: «John Smith», «userRole»: «Admin» }.
S9Zs/8/uEGGTVVtLggFTizCsMtwOJnRhjaQ2BMUQhcY
Здесь можно подробнее прочитать:
https://sohabr.net/habr/post/262817/?version=110667

Comment: Можно ли найти в приведенном тексте ответ на вопрос "зачем используется base64 в jwt"?

Comment: "Пример подписанного JWT токена ..." - показывает во что превращается обмен. Эта последовательность, содержащая ограниченные символы, легко передается. BASE64 используется, для представления бинарных файлов в тексте письма (транспортное кодирование).

Comment: "во что", но не "зачем"